# First time iPhone user here, some of my App icons on my Home Screen sometimes “blink” (turn to grey for a second), whats the meaning of it?

Tags: iphone, ios

i've just got my first iPhone (7), and i'm kinda new to the iOS and everything, but today i've noticed something that i'm not exactly sure what it was, but it seemed like some of my App's icons on my homescreen blinked/flickered (turned grey) for just a sec in a random order, then went immediately back to normal, is there any info on what happened?

Comment: Did the apps auto-upgrade perhaps? You can check the recent updated apps in the App Store (tap on profile pic at top right, then scroll down)

Answer (score 3):

The app likely updated. When the app update is installing, the app is temporarily unavailable.

Alternatively, iOS may be cleaning the app. If your device is running low on space, iOS may delete temporary/cache data from the app’s container. This will temporarily make the app unavailable, for a couple seconds and show ‘Cleaning…’ in place of the app name.